# Terms of use data from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bigdata

easy question - if I get data from search graph Facebook (ex. list of all pages or events - anything what I can retrivie) can I use them in my own site, publish them? comercial use?

Or is there any restriction?

thx

EDIT:

I need public data like fan pages or public events, but I want use them out of Facebook, on anther site (present data in my own way). Good example is socialbakers - big statistics from FB ([example](http://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/facebook/pages/total/media/online-media/)

is there possybillity to make that site based on Facebook API data?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: You can find the Facebook Platform Policy at https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: BTW, most ways from FB dev support lead here, (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/). Only Stackoferflow or group about it on Facebook, that's all. Or give me right link?

Comment: Hi @Mikołaj, have you found any useful answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of data you want to get, as there can be personal information, pages, events, etc.

You can find everything about your question over here: https://developers.facebook.com/policy .

Comment: I need public data like fan pages or public events, but I want use them out of Facebook, on anther site (present data in my own way). Good example is socialbakers - big statistics from FB ([example][1]


  [1]: http://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/facebook/pages/total/media/online-media/

is there possybillity to make that site based on Facebook API data?