# Facebook API Graph - Search for events (access token)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try search the the pages and the events by two different calls (still using Graph Explorer):

search?fields=name&q=warsaw&type=page

search?fields=name &q=warsaw&type=event

The second (events object) works only with user token. When I generate app token there is invalid token error. Is it possibile to get results for second query with app token? It’s important for me, I need use it in my own code.

Can I generale user token within scripts (HTTPS request),

OR generale long time user token (I mean user token for my own profile)

OR (most desired solution) get results for secong call above (type=event), by app token?

UPDATE:

Ok, sory, so it’s clearly that app token doesn’t support search for event (but I still don’t understand why – events, such as page is public object and it doesn’t contain a private data).

I’m going to clarify another way. I’d like to download information about events and use it in my own site (database) as public. This operation’s objective is create database of FB events (something like Eventbrite). So I need make that set as public (belongs to app/site, not user profile).

I know that’s not a standard usage of Facebook API, but if it infringes the FB policy, please write me – I haven’t find clearly statement for that. I’ve ask about it here [Terms of use data from Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768541/terms-of-use-data-from-facebook-api/27768573#27768573). I guess it’s legal.

Now. I can retrieve events by page node (get all events for each page), but it’s strongly uneffective – only few page of whole are the event’s organisators. I need explore directly events.

Is there any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just consult the Facebook docs? It clearly stated in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

that

> - Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

So, **no**, you can't just use an app access token to search for events.

Regarding login, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: thanks, sory for mistake, please read my another explanation (update)

Comment: It's not possible other than collecting lists of page_ids and requesting them. For the event search, you'll need an user access token

Comment: I can manually put user token to code and download events to database, but it's stupid... (but maybe it's solution with long term user token - what do you think?), another hope full thing may be get events frome place node. I use call "search?fields=name,events&limit=300&q=new+york&type=place", it works, but not in full (missing events that exist)

Comment: The link you posted doesn't say what you quoted - I guess it must have changed. Does anyone know how to get public events for my own page with an App Access Token? This is getting ridiculous. Didn't know something so simple could be so hard.

Comment: This is no longer possible afaik.